# Neutering anxiety

Tags: cats, behavior, veterinarian

[image] 
My cat was a rescued cat I believe was feral. He loves me but is scared of other people. I want to neuter him soon. How can I reduce his anxiety when I do get him fixed. Also I'm curious what breed(s) he may be. He's a very large cat compared to others, maybe 15- 20lbs

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the vet to make him the first neuter of the day. That will minimise the amount of time he spends in an unfamiliar place waiting for surgery, and minimise the number of other animals he sees or smells. Also, you can ask them to call you as soon as he's nearly ready to go home, so you can come pick him up.

If he's *terrified* of other people, you can probably get a sedative from the vet to give him before you bring him in. But it's probably best to avoid that if possible, to minimise the chance of any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Short term solution: 
You can ask the pharmacist or your vet to give you some calming pills or spray for your cat.

It would be great if they could give you a sleeping pill for your cat. This way your cat would be asleep when going to the vet.


Long term solution:
Clicker training (counterconditioning and desensitisation). 
If you google 'clicker training' you'll find lots and lots of things mostly for dogs. Most of these things work for any other pet.

Answer (score 0):

About what breed he may be - if he was feral, then he is probably a domestic short haired tabby cat (i.e. a moggie, Heinz57, or mutt).  That is not a bad thing, as all my moggies have been great companions.   As for weight, each cat is different, so weights can vary.   As long as there is a 'waist' right before his hind legs (ignore the primordial pouch).  His vet should be able to provide guidelines.  Congratulations on adopting a companion cat!